# Failure to emit CSS link HTML using html_receive and html_post

Tags: css, web-services, swi-prolog, html-head

I am trying to do something very straightforward... emit some HTML content with a link to my style sheet, as explained here, on the [SWI-Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWI-Prolog) page: *Repositioning HTML for CSS and JavaScript links*:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=html-post

The only included library is:

```
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
```

I have my generic dcg rule for outputting the CSS content, exactly as per the example:

```
css(URL) -->
    html_post(css,
      link([ type('text/css'),
             rel('stylesheet'),
             href(URL)
           ])).
```

Then the example says 'Next we insert the unique CSS links...', but the example given doesn't supply a parameter for the unique URL to be inserted. So I'm guessing at this:

```
reply_html_page([title('mytitle'), \html_receive(css('/my.css'))],
[
  div([id='mydivid'], 'divstuff..'
  )
]).
```

But running it does not output the CSS content as expected... The title gets processed, but the CSS link is missing.

```html
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>mytitle</title>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mydivid">divstuff..</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looking at the trace, the CSS dcg rule never gets executed (version 6.6.4).

Perhaps the solution needs to include html_receive/2(+Id, :Handler), rather than /1, but there are no simple copy/paste/run examples which would explain its usage. The code snippet for html_receive/2 contains html_post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used a simple/atomic identifier in `html_post//1` and `html_receive//1`, both to make the example easier and to stay closer to the SWI-Prolog documentation. This identifier can also be a compound, but I did not get the use for that in your example.

The following code opens a Web browser with the generated HTML page. Standard HTML inspection tools show that the `link` element is there now.

```
:- module(css_include, []).

:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(www_browser)).

:- http_server(http_dispatch, [port(5000)]).
:- http_handler(root(test), test, []).

test(_):-
  reply_html_page(
    [title('mytitle'),\html_receive(my_css_link)],
    \html_body_stuff
  ),
  www_open_url('http://localhost:5000/test').

html_body_stuff -->
  {Url = 'http://www.swi-prolog.org'},
  html_post(
    my_css_link,
    link([type('text/css'),rel('stylesheet'),href(Url)])
  ).
```

**Edit:** Based on a comment by @magus I have included the 'normal' way of generating an HTML page with a CSS link in the header, i.e. without using the `html_post//1` and `html_receive//1`. This may be useful for comparison with the other code snippet.

```
:- module(css_include, []).

:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(www_browser)).

:- http_server(http_dispatch, [port(5000)]).
:- http_handler(root(test), test, []).

test(_):-
  reply_html_page(
    [title('mytitle'),\a_css_link('http://www.swi-prolog.org')],
    \html_body_stuff
  ).

a_css_link(Url) -->
  html(link([type('text/css'),rel('stylesheet'),href(Url)])).

html_body_stuff -->
  html(h1('HTML body over here.')).
```

The clause `a_css_link//1` can be reused for other URIs as requested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So.. if I have this correct, you are using the dcg rule that gets called to build the html body to bind the link url to my_css_link, so that url gets inserted after the title ? Is there no elegant way to keep the head and body separate... logically, the <body> need not be concerned the <head> ?

Comment: Also, I was looking to make the dcg to build the css general purpose, so I can re-use it for multiple urls.  Then have another dcg for js.

Comment: @magus Keeping the head and body generation separate is what happens by default. `http_post/1` and `http_receive/1` exist specifically with the purpose to intermingle HTML generation. A common use case would be this: You generate an HTML page with widgets that require additional JS/CSS to be loaded. Which widgets are included on the page is decided upon page load and can be different each time. You can then add a JS/CSS links to the header for each widget that you generate in the HTML body. This makes generating the header easy, since you do not have to ponder which widgets are loaded.

Comment: Got it - thanks. I was over-complicating it by trying to use that mailman stuff, which I can now see has it's uses.  Your 2 examples laid out side-by-side in the swi docs would have been very useful.. the current docs are very api-centric, rather than use-case/example-centric, and it makes 'picking the right tool for the job' more complicated.

Comment: @magus I think you make a valid point there. You may want to check out the [tutorial on Web programming in SWI-Prolog](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html) by Anne Ogborn. It is more use-case based and comes with working sample code and assignments.

Comment: As it is shown here, is it valid syntax highlighting (e.g. "module" in blue)? If not, perhaps turn syntax highlighting off by "[`lang-none`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)"?